# Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView Error despite being installed on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, xamarin

I could only find the work around on Windows, not Mac

In order to fix this error, it is said to delete any `Android.Support.*` folders in

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Xamarin\
```

What folder should I look at if I am using Mac OSX?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote most of this documentation awhile back that you can find here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/#Automatic_Recovery_from_m2repository_Errors

For macOS you can use `/Users/username/.local/share/Xamarin`